# Javascript validation check not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-debugging

I am trying to check javascript validations on some fields in visualforce page. Following is my code.

```
<apex:page >

     <html> 
         <head>
             <script>

              function testit(){
             if ( document.getElementById('answer1').value.length > 10000){
                     alert( "Answer for Question 1 can contain only 10000 characters" );
                     document.getElementById('answer1').focus();
                     return false;
                }
                if ( document.getElementById('answer2').value.length > 10000){
                     alert( "Answer for Question 2 can contain only 10000 characters" );
                     document.getElementById('answer2').focus();
                     return false;
                }
                if ( document.getElementById('answer3').value.length > 10000){
                     alert( "Answer for Question 3 can contain only 10000 characters" );
                     document.getElementById('answer3').focus();
                     return false;
                }
                if ( document.getElementById('answer4').value.length > 10000){
                     alert( "Answer for Question 4 can contain only 10000 characters" );
                     document.getElementById('answer4').focus();
                     return false;
                    }
                   if ( document.getElementById('answer5').value.length > 10000){
                     alert( "Answer for Question 5 can contain only 10000 characters" );
                     document.getElementById('answer5').focus();
                     return false;
                    }
                  }
             </script>
         </head>
        <body>
            <apex:form >

            <p style="font-weight:bold;">Question 1</p>
                            <textarea id="answer1" name="answer1" rows="10" cols="100"/>

                            <p style="font-weight:bold;">Question 2 </p>
                            <textarea id="answer2" name="answer2" rows="10" cols="100"/>

                            <p style="font-weight:bold;">Question 3</p>
                            <textarea id="answer3" name="answer3" rows="10" cols="100"/>

                            <p style="font-weight:bold;">Question 5 </p>
                            <textarea id="answer5" name="answer5" rows="10" cols="100"/>

            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="return(testit())" styleClass="button button1"  />

            </apex:form>
         </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

In some cases question 4 is not rendered to the page, so in my current code, I get the validation error for Question 1, 2 and 3 only but I dont get the error on question 5. Please help me understand why the error is not firing for question 5.

Comment: Check question no.4 display hide or show before validate this

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<script>` Javascript code below the `<apex:form>` code.  The Javascript will only be able to find the elements if they've already been defined

Answer (score 0):

try this might help

```
<apex:page >

 <html> 
     <head>
     </head>
    <body>
        <apex:form >

        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Question 1</p>
                        <textarea id="answer1" name="answer1" rows="10" cols="100"/>

                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Question 2 </p>
                        <textarea id="answer2" name="answer2" rows="10" cols="100"/>

                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Question 3</p>
                        <textarea id="answer3" name="answer3" rows="10" cols="100"/>

                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Question 5 </p>
                        <textarea id="answer5" name="answer5" rows="10" cols="100"/>

        <apex:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="return(testit())" styleClass="button button1"  />

        </apex:form>
     </body>
     <noscript>Opps! Please enable javascript for better experience</noscript>
     <script>
         const testit = () => {
            if ( document.getElementById('answer1').value.length > 10000){
                 alert( "Answer for Question 1 can contain only 10000 characters" );
                 document.getElementById('answer1').focus();
                 return false;
            }
            if ( document.getElementById('answer2').value.length > 10000){
                 alert( "Answer for Question 2 can contain only 10000 characters" );
                 document.getElementById('answer2').focus();
                 return false;
            }
            if ( document.getElementById('answer3').value.length > 10000){
                 alert( "Answer for Question 3 can contain only 10000 characters" );
                 document.getElementById('answer3').focus();
                 return false;
            }
            if ( document.getElementById('answer4').value.length > 10000){
                 alert( "Answer for Question 4 can contain only 10000 characters" );
                 document.getElementById('answer4').focus();
                 return false;
                }
            if ( document.getElementById('answer5').value.length > 10000){
                 alert( "Answer for Question 5 can contain only 10000 characters" );
                 document.getElementById('answer5').focus();
                 return false;
            }
         }
     </script>
</html>
```